# What is the keyboard shortcut for pasting without formatting in Powerpoint?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, copy-paste, paste

In Microsoft Powerpoint 2019, if I want to paste using: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, that doesn't work, what is the new shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works for me.

There are more answers for [Word here](https://superuser.com/questions/1376470/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-without-formatting-in-ms-word), most of which work for PowerPoint (why you can't customize shortcuts I don't know).  Notably, paste text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>); then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for paste options to appear; then press <kbd>T</kbd> for pasting the text with "Keep text only" paste option.

Comment: You cannot modify PowerPoint's shortcuts, because years ago stupid Microsoft, hunger for money as usual, signed a stupid business agreement to make this feature available [in form of paid plug-in only](https://pptproductivity.com/pricing). Now you are a victim of everlasting eagerness of Microsoft and have two options: pay insanely high 150 bucks per year or live with default keyboard shortcuts only. This is [at least 11 years old problem](https://onezeronull.com/2012/01/11/changing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-powerpoint-costs-40-usd/).

Comment: Yes, you are correct -- Microsoft enforces you to pay for changing keyboard shortcuts (plus 180 other useless features) **the same amount** (149 USD per)  **as you would actually pay for the entire Microsoft 365 Business Standard package** (12.50 USD per month = 150 USD per year). Can't find words to express what I am thinking about this idea and policy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a collection of AutoHotKey scripts called [aC‘TivAid](https://www.heise.de/download/product/activaid-24593) in which you can find a tool called PatePlain which can do exactly what you want, but OS wide so that you will never need to search for this in another program again. In addition to this you will find other useful tools like system wide text replacement like date, mail or anything else you want to add; a shortcut to google the selected text and many others.

There is a newer version available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ewerybody/a2), but that is still in beta.

This maybe is not the answer you were looking for, but maybe someone else who comes here finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint on it's own doesn't have customizable shortcut keys.
In my opinion as a workaround you can create a Quick Access Toolbar for paste and keep text only option.

Go to **File**- **Options**- **Quick Access Toolbar**- **All Commands**- **Keep Text onlyPaste and Keep Text Only**:
[image]

Then you can enable the Quick Access Toolbar and click the option directly:
[image]